# How can I debug problems with my Python code?

Tags: python

```
def sum(x):
    sum=0
    for x in range (10):
        sum+=x
    return sum
print (sum(10))
```

In this sentence, if I type sum(10) or sum(100), It goes the same answer,why is it?

Comment: Many mistakes in your code. (1) sum is already a builtin function. You can use it directly (2) You are not using the argument x correctly. Instead you have hardcoded 10. This is why you are getting the same answer.

Comment: Just use the python builtin `sum(range(10))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here range is fixed. Need to change this `range (10)` to `range (x)`, As range is fixed to 10.

Comment: This is a bad way of doing it as x is used as an index. Never use variables for more than one thing.

Comment: You mean my sentence range(10) is wrong? It limits the last sentence?

Comment: No, he would have `for x in range(x)` if he did it your way.

Comment: harsh dv, technically he is using the same variable name twice but it works and it explains to the OP what their error is.

Comment: @meyer9 this doesn't cause any effect whether x is used as index.

Comment: It does not cause a bad effect, but it is very bad practice.

Comment: @cwcauc range(10) is wrong, as every time you passes value of x, for all these values range should be same 0 to 9

Comment: @meyer9 here my mistake i din't looked over index variable. But for me it is not a bad practise, as i am using same memory for index and limit. This saved variables memory. Don't you thinks so.

Comment: @cwcauc if you need pythonic approach for this then try this code also sum(range(x)) or reduce (lambda x,y:x+y, range(x))

Answer (score 1):

```
def sum(x):
    sum=0
    for i in range (x):
        sum+=i
    return sum
print (sum(100))
```

It is giving you the same result because you are using the same constant in range(10). use the variable you passed in .

```
def sum(y):
    sum = 0
    for x in range(10):
        sum += y
    return sum
print(sum(10))
```

This is the second though as per your question if you want to add your variable 10 time.

Answer (score 0):

This for loop sets x to 0 and runs the code inside over and over until it gets to 10. If you wanted to add x 10 times, you'd have to do something like this:

```
def sum(y):
    sum = 0
    for x in range(10):
        sum += y
    return sum
print(sum(10))
```

If you wanted to add up all digits to x, you'd do something like this:

```
def sum(x):
    sum=0
    for i in range(x):
        sum+=i
    return sum
print(sum(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are not using the argument you sent to function. range function will only range till 10 with current code.[See range function doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)

May be you can do like this

```
def sum(x):
    sum=0
    for y in range (x):
        sum+=y
    return sum
print (sum(10))
```

Answer (score -1):

u try like,

```
   def sum(x):
        sum=0
        for y in range (x):
            sum+=y
            print(sum)
        return sum
    print (sum(100))
```